# Error compiling ESP32 Wrover Module in Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, linux, cpp

SO i have been getting this error window when i compile a simple code to run different LED lights on the ESP32-S2-SOLA (Wrovere) module

Code:

```cpp
int LED_BUILTIN = 2;
    
void setup() {
    pinMode (LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}
    
void loop() {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}
```

error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.15 (Linux), Board: "ESP32 Wrover Module, Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS), QIO, 80MHz, 115200, None"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/student/.arduino15/packages/esp32/tools/esptool_py/3.0.0/esptool.py", line 38, in <module>
    import serial
ImportError: No module named serial
exit status 1
Error compiling for board ESP32 Wrover Module.
```

Comment: "ImportError: No module named serial"

Comment: Install `python3-serial`

Answer (score 1):

The error can be solved by installing Python serial package via these two commands

$ sudo apt-get update -y
$ sudo apt-get install -y python-serial

Answer (score 0):

As Juraj and Majenko pointed out in the comments, your python installation lacks the module `serial`.
In Linux the best way to install it would be `pip` or rather `pip3` for Python 3:

```
sudo pip3 install serial
```

If you don't have `pip3` on you system, install `python3-pip` first, e. g. using `apt`:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: I did both, it still shows the following error

Comment: I made it work, thank you for the help